# Using Jquery autocomplete data to check HTML checkboxes

Tags: jquery, database, checkbox, autocomplete, tags

what im trying to do is make a tagging system using Jquery and autocomplete, where the autocompletions are tags already on a database, and as you click, hidden HTML checkboxes for each get checked.

To achieve that i guess i need to retrieve the IDs of the fields i'm currently only getting the "names" of, right? I guess i can figure out how to get both name and ID. But how do i use said ID to check a certain HTML checkbox?

Sorry if this has been answered, or my post is too vague. I'm new to all this.

EDIT: i can't get the ID data without it showing up on the autocomplete list. (and said list also behaves strangely) any help with that too? i assume i need to set data[0] as label and data[1] as value, or something like that.. 
If i can retrieve said ID without it fucking up my autocomplete i can take care of the rest. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to check a checkbox with a given id as follows

```
$('#id').prop('checked', true);
```

EDIT: Yes refer to the jquery autocomplete documentation.  I am assuming you are using Jquery UI.  You can set the label to what you would like to be displayed and the value to the corresponding id.  Then you can reference that id when checking the checkbox.  I have modified the select function of the documentation to something that could work for your case.

```
$( "#project" ).autocomplete({
  minLength: 0,
  source: projects,
  focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
    return false;
  },
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    var id = "#" + ui.item.value;
    $(id).prop('checked',true);

    return false;
  }
})
```

Comment: What if i wanted to use hidden inputs? what should i use instead of "checked"? Thanks for your help

Comment: Well since an input cannot be both hidden and a checkbox I would suggest using a checkbox input and then setting visibility to hidden in the css.

Comment: thanks a lot. If i can solve the issue i just added on EDIT i'm all set.

Comment: Thanks man you pretty much wrote the file for me. oh and the jquery documentation seems lacking in my opinion. I haven't seen any hints to the "ui.item.label" for example, except on tutorials on some other websites. Maybe i don't know how to use it.